# Cannot cast from int to String[] in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

`String[] arrayOfString2 =(String[])0;`

The above line shows type casting error. But i have copied it from some other program and there is no error there. What can i do?

Comment: It's not possible. Are you sure the program from which you copied that is written in Java ?

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve here? an array of integers to an array of strings?

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to cast an `int` (zero in your case) to an array of Strings. The other code was probably casting a variable `o` or less probably `O` to an array of Strings.

Try printing out the variable to a console to see what's its class and value to be sure if it can be casted to a certain type. Something like:

```
System.out.println("variable: " + var);
String[] arrayOfStrings = (String[])var;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast an `int` to a `String[]` in Java. You never could and you never will be able  to.

The reason for this is that Java has [strong typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_typed_programming_language).

I don't believe that the other code compiled.

Answer (score 0):

This code is probably in Groovy, you can't do this in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide more information about what type of `Object` you're trying to cast to a `String[]`.

As others have pointed out

```
String[] arrayOfString2 =(String[])0;
```

Won't work because you can't cast an `int` (in your case `0`) to a `String[]`.

Did you mean to write `o` and not `0` by any chance? If you did mean `o` and it was actually a `String[]` you should be able to cast it via the way you tried, that is the following will compile (although you would probably never want to declare the `String[]` as an `Object` only to cast it later).

```
Object o = new String[0];
String[] arrayOfString2 =(String[])o;
```

Although this isn't very useful because it has no space for any elements. Instead you might want

```
String[] arrayOfString2 = new String[sizeOfArray];
```

Answer (score 0):

This code, as already said, is not valid in Java.
It probably should be:

```
String[] arrayOfString2 = null;
```

just a guess, without knowing what this is for.